# Testing focus() on an element in an AngularJS directive template

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, jasmine, jasmine-jquery

Given the following directive

```
directive('myDirective', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {},
        replace: false,
        template: '<input ng-focus="onFocus()" type="text" />',
        link: function(scope, element, attr) {
            scope.onFocus = function() {
                console.log('got focus');
            };
        }
    };
});
```

I've tested that the focus watcher works in a browser, but I'd like to be able to trigger it in a unit test.  This is what I've tried but it isn't working.

```
var element = angular.element('<div my-directive></div>');
$compile(element)($scope);
$scope.$digest();
element.find('input')[0].focus();
```

I can see that I am correctly getting to the input box with the find call, and I would expect that code to trigger the focus event on the input box, but nothing is happening.  What am I missing here?

Comment: I don't think you need to do `element.find('input')` the element _is_ the input tag

Comment: Replace is set to false.  `element` is the div and contained within it is the input tag.

Comment: Oh, I missed that part

Comment: Try `element.find('input').triggerHandler('focus')`;

Comment: No such luck with `$(element.find('input')[0]).triggerHandler('focus');`

Comment: Sorry didn't read what you said. I did exactly that and it worked.  Any thoughts on filling in with text?

Comment: Let me post a answer as it could help other people

Comment: element.find('input').val('hello world'). Kindly accept as answer when you can.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

When trying to trigger events on angular elements, one should use the [triggerHandler()](http://api.jquery.com/triggerHandler/) function which is just really jqLite function and not angulars and then pass in the event as a string parameter as shown below.

```
element.find('input').triggerHandler('focus');
```

To perform any other functions on an angular element, read the documentation [here](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/angular.element), it shows you a list of functions available to angular elements