# Angular - cannot name the element - how to access model attribute like $focus?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I'm using a custom directive which appends some html including a input I have to refer to. The problem is I cannot name this input. I need to get $focus property. How to do this? I mean normally I would use something like:

```
ng-show="myForm.myElement.$focus"
```

but since it's impossible I'm looking for something like

```
ng-show="angular.getModelFor('#closestElement > input').$focus"
```

but of course this function does not exist. There's one which makes me able to refer to the $element itself, namely

```
angular.element(document.querySelector('#closestElement > input'))
```

but this only gives me HTML/jQuery element which does not contain the required field $focus. How to refer to it in similar manner?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Instead to get $focus property, why can't you use ng-focus directive and achieve your functionality.

if you want $focus property for the element,use directive link function you will get ele.

[Testing focus() on an element in an AngularJS directive template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21411003/testing-focus-on-an-element-in-an-angularjs-directive-template)

```
> <div ng-app="App" ng-controller="Ctrl">
>     Name: <input ng-focus="errors('hide')" ng-blur="errors('show')" />
>     <p ng-show="!showErrors">focus</p>
>     <p ng-show="showErrors">blur</p> </div>
> 
> angular.module('App', []) .controller('Ctrl', ['$scope',
> function($scope){
>      $scope.showErrors = true;
>    
>      $scope.errors = function(action){
>          if(action==="show"){
>             $scope.showErrors = true;
>          }else{
>             $scope.showErrors = false;
>          }
>     } }]);
```

Comment: It's not what I meant. Those are two different elements, one of which I have no control of. The first element should be shown when the other is focused but I cannot name the one being focused.

Comment: if my understanding towards your problem is correct. if you want to trigger events from outside angular going with jquery lite is the option http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21411003/testing-focus-on-an-element-in-an-angularjs-directive-template.

Comment: I don't want to trigger events. I'd like to know if element is focused.